# Does there exist a polynomial (,) which detects all non-squares?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438559/does-there-exist-a-polynomial-px-y-which-detects-all-non-squares) in MathStackExchange back in April, and it received more than 30 upvotes, but no answer was offered even after a bounty. I am reposting it here in hopes that someone can answer it.

**Problem.** Does there exist a two-variable polynomial $P(x, y)$ with integer coefficients such that a positive integer $n$ is **not** a perfect square *if and only if* there is a pair $(x, y)$ of positive integers such that $P(x, y)=n$?

**Context.** The answer is positive for polynomials in 3 variables! This appeared as a problem in USA Team Selection Test in 2013. It turns out that the polynomial $P(x, y, z)=z^2\cdot (x^2-zy^2-1)^2+z$  enjoys the following property: a positive integer $n$ is a not a perfect square if and only if $P(x, y, z)=n$ has a solution in positive integers $(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{N}^{3}$. This construction works nicely due to Pell's equation. If $n$ is not a perfect square, then Pell's equation $x^2-ny^2=1$ has a solution in positive integers $(x_0, y_0)$, and so we get $P(x_0, y_0, n) = n$. Conversely, if $P(x, y, z)=n$, then one can show that $n$ cannot be a perfect square because $n=z^2(x^2-zy^2-1)^2+z$ can be squeezed between two consecutive perfect squares:
$$
 (z(x^2-zy^2-1))^2 < n < (z(|x^2-zy^2-1|+1)^2
$$

**Remark.** It is clear that there is no single-variable polynomial $P(x)$ which could achieve the desired property. Indeed, there are arbitrary number of consecutive non-squares, and a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n>1$ cannot output a consecutive list of $n+1$ numbers. This last claim itself is a nice problem; for a solution, see Example 2.24 in page 11 of *Number Theory: Concepts and Problems* by Andreescu, Dospinescu and Mushkarov.

Comment: Notice that $(x+y-1)(x+y)/2+y$ detects all non-triangular numbers.

Comment: Along similar lines to @IlyaBogdanov's comment, $P(x, y) = \frac{(x+y)^2 + 2(x-y) + 1}4$ detects non-squares, but doesn't meet the requirement of integral coefficients.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Cute! How about non-cubes;)?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, I suspect you are aware of the problem, but the people who upvoted your comment may not be. The same construction would give $Q(x, y) = \frac{-(x+y)^3 + 267(x+y)^2 + 1161(x+y) + 12960x - 7907}{12960}$ but because the spacing of the antidiagonals is no longer consistent we run into the occasional integer value in the gaps, and so it does represent some cubes.

Comment: For 3 variables the theory of Pell's equation is a huge overkill: $(x+y+z-1)^2-(4x+2y-4)$ works just as nicely.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a long comment that might be helpful:

Treat $a$ as a parameter, and treat $x$ as a variable.  The Diophantine expression
$$
\exists x\ ((x^2<a) \land (a<(x+1)^2))
$$
defines $a$ as a nonsquare.  Adding two more variables, we can remove the inequalities.  To that end, let
$$
D(a,x,y,z):=(x^2+y-a)^2+(a+z-(x+1)^2)^2.
$$
Then $a$ is a nonsquare exactly when there are positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $D(a,x,y,z)=0$.  Now, for the new polynomial
$$
E(w,x,y,z):=w(1-D(w,x,y,z)^2),
$$
its positive outputs (on positive inputs) are exactly the positive nonsquares (although there are possibly nonpositive outputs).

We can reduce the number of variables needed to define $D$ from three to two by using an idea of Carl Schildkraut (taken from a comment to the MSE version of the question).  Use
$$
D(a,x,y):=((x+y-1)^2+x-a)\cdot ((x+y-1)^2+(x+y-1)+x-a)
$$
instead.  There is a corresponding $3$-variable $E$.

To answer the question fully it would suffice to find a $1$-variable version of $D$.
The hope here is that we could somehow translate Peter Taylor's near miss to this situation, where fractional considerations become less relevant.

Comment: It should be noted that the almost-answer I proposed in comments evaluates to non-integers when $x+y$ is even, so removing the fractional component could cause new problems.

Comment: A direct approach along these lines would be to target $(x^2 + y)[1 \le y \le 2x]$ as $(x^2 + y)[1 \le y,z][y+z = 2x + 1]$ giving $$E(x,y,z) = (x^2 + y)(1 - (2x-y-z+1)^2)$$ I'm not sure that it makes it easier to eliminate the third variable, though.

Answer (score -2):

Here's some argument constraining the form of $P$.

Let $P(x, y)$ have highest $x$ degree $a$ and $y$ degree $b$. Then $a = b = 2$.

Suppose that $b = 1$ and $P(x, y) = a(x) + b(x)y$. This now heuristically covers $\sum_{x=M}^{\sqrt[a]{N}} \frac{1}{b(x)}$ of a constant density subset (discard the small bad residues) of $N$, which can only hold if $a = 1$ holds as well.

Now, let $P(x, y) = axy + bx + cy + d$. By SFFT and clearing rationals, we get that $c_1(c_2 x + c_3)(c_4 y + c_5) + c_6  = c_7 n$ has a solution iff $n$ is not a square. We must have that $c_1 \mid c_7$, so we can simplify to get $(c_2 x + c_3)(c_4 y + c_5) = c_7 n - c_6$. By Dirichlet's, $c_7n - c_6$ sometime is $\gcd(c_6, c_7) \cdot p$ for a prime $p$. It follows that one of $c_2 x + c_3, c_4 y + c_5$ divides the $\gcd(c_6, c_7)$, and the other is chosen to divide everything else. WLOG we fix $c_2 x + c_3$. Then $c_4 y + c_5$ must divide $C \cdot p$ where $C$ comes from a finite set, which by Dirichlet's forcecs $c_4 \mid c_7$ and $c_5 \equiv c_6 \pmod{c_4}$. However at this point we've just a found way to construct a perfect square by doing exactly this, contradiction.

Comment: Have you shown that $a=b=2$? It looks as if all that you've proven is that $a\ge2$ and $b\ge2$.

Comment: What is SFFT, please?